# Can someone factory reset it? if its (5.0)OS and has a lock

Tags: lost-phone

My phone was stolen (it has a password) and I remember that its OS was 5.0. Can the theif factory reset it?

Answer (score 2):

They will be able to factory reset the device from Recovery.  However, if your device has Factory Reset Protection (not all 5.0 devices do) then they will require your Google Account password to access the device on first boot, so the phone will not be usable.  Joel's answer mentions Android Device Manager — note that it will not work after a factory reset, and you have to have set it up beforehand as well.

Unlike Joel I would assume that yes, much of your data is recoverable *unless you device was encrypted*.  I see no reason to believe that manufacturers started doing proper full wipes beginning with KitKat just because the researchers didn't test those devices!  Files that were simply deleted / had their headers destroyed / etc. can usually be recovered because all of their data is still there physically, the OS/filesystem just doesn't know about it.

Also note that if your device's bootloader was unlocked, they could flash a custom recovery and access your data that way without a factory reset (again assuming an unencrypted device).  It might be possible to do this without a custom recovery as well depending on the features provided by the stock recovery.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , factory reset will erase all data , including the password.
However he will not be able to recover the data (to the best of my knowledge)
According [to this website](https://www.androidpit.com/why-a-factory-reset-doesn-t-wipe-all-your-data)

> It must be noted that devices running Android 4.4 and above were not tested, so it is not clear whether devices running Android KitKat and Lollipop are also affected, although the researchers were quick to point out that it’s plausible that they could be.

If you are looking to locate it then use [google device manager.](https://www.google.co.uk/android/devicemanager)
Sign in to the same account as your phone was signed in and it will show you the location of when it was last online.
Hope that helps